# Perl: find if a variable's value matches that in an array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I'm a perl newbie. I have a code in which a variable is loaded with several values during a foreach loop. What I want to do is to perform some operation on that variable only if its in that array. What is the **most efficient** way to do this in perl as the data I am working on is very large.

A simple example of my question is, say I have an array of fruits I want

```
@fruits_i_like = qw (mango banana apple);
```

But I have a $fruit variable in a foreach loop which gets the name of fruits from a data file that has all different types of fruits. How would I pick only those cases of $fruit that are in my @fruits_i_like array?

Comment: well the file I need to read is about 50MB.

Comment: @sfactor : That's not too bad then.

Comment: If the data file is stable, put the data in an SQLite database, create indexes, then use `DBI` to issue the appropriate `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @Sinan : That might be overkill for a newbie, especially seeing that the file isn't too large.

Comment: When you iterate over your file, make sure you use `while ( my $line = <$fh> ) { blah }` instead of `for my $line ( <$fh> ) { blah }`  The difference between these is context, `while` operates in a scalar (boolean) context.  `for` operates in list context and will load the entire file into memory before beginning to process it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a hash like this :

```
my %h = map {$_ => 1 } @fruits_i_like;
if (exists $h{$this_fruit}) {
    # do stuff
}
```

Here is a benchmark that compare this way vs mfontani solution

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my @fruits_i_like = qw/mango banana apple/;
my $this_fruit = 'banana';
my %h = map {$_ => 1 } @fruits_i_like;
my $count = -3;
my $r = cmpthese($count, {
    'grep' => sub {
         if ( scalar grep $this_fruit eq $_, @fruits_i_like ) {
             # do stuff
         }
    },
    'hash' => sub {
        if (exists $h{$this_fruit}) {
             # do stuff
        }
    },
});
```

Output:

```
          Rate grep hash
grep 1074911/s   -- -76%
hash 4392945/s 309%   --
```

Comment: Change the `sub{}` to `q{}` and run that benchmark again.  The subroutine call overhead can change the numbers too much.

Comment: If you create %h just for this purpose, shouldn't it be part of the benchmark?

Comment: @Øyvind Skaar: I don't think so, because OP wants to match fruits many times. %h is created only once and used many times. It's different from the grep solution where the grep is done for every different fruit.

Answer (score 11):

Perl 5.10 or higher?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;
my @fruits_i_like = qw/mango banana apple/;
my $this_fruit = 'banana';
if ( $this_fruit ~~ \@fruits_i_like ) {
     say "yummy, I like $this_fruit!";
}
```

Before 5.10:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @fruits_i_like = qw/mango banana apple/;
my $this_fruit = 'banana';
if ( scalar grep $this_fruit eq $_, @fruits_i_like ) {
     print "yummy, I like $this_fruit!\n";
}
```

The downside is that the *whole* array is parsed through to find matches. This may not be the best option, in which case you can use `List::MoreUtils`' `any()`, which returns true once it matches a value and doesn't continue going through the array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw/any/;
my @fruits_i_like = qw/mango banana apple/;
my $this_fruit = 'banana';
if ( any { $this_fruit eq $_ } @fruits_i_like ) {
     print "yummy, I like $this_fruit!\n";
}
```

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 9):

This is effectively a lookup problem. It'd be faster to lookup the values of `@fruits_i_like` in a hash like `%fruits_i_like` (which is O(1) vs the O(n) of an array).

Convert the array to a hash using the following operation:

```
open my $data, '<', 'someBigDataFile.dat' or die "Unable to open file: $!";

my %wantedFruits;
@wantedFruits{@fruits_i_like} = ();  # All fruits_i_like entries are now keys

while (my $fruit = <$data>) {        # Iterates over data file line-by-line

     next unless exists $wantedFruits{$fruit};  # Go to next entry unless wanted

     # ... code will reach this point only if you have your wanted fruit
}
```